How to present serious flaws in third-party software to non-technical users
We have third party software being tested. Our software has to interface with this, hence my involvement. There are some things I consider serious technical flaws. I'd like to communicate these things in a manner that non-technical users of the software can understand. I think the best way is to provide non-technical analogies of the issues as well as an idea of the seriousness of the issues.
Issue 1: Database with no foreign keys
There seems to be some debate as to the importance of doing this. The main argument against it is being that it's something enforceable in code. I'm on the other side of the argument. My worries revolve around:

Is this integrity checking code tested well enough?
Multiple applications may be working with the same database. That's the case here since not only does this third-party software access it, but mine does as well. The more applications involved, the more difficult it is to make sure quality integrity checking happens everywhere. It may also be important to note that I'm required to interface directly with their database rather than through an API, so I don't have the luxury of relying on their logic. If I did, this might not be as important of a point.
I feel like ad-hoc queries should be accounted for. That means integrity checking code would have to exist on the database, not in code.

Some research into this also led me to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18717/are-foreign-keys-really-necessary-in-a-database-design. In fact, I could probably reference that for this particular issue, especially with comments such as:
A database schema without FK constraints is like driving without a seat belt.

That seems easy enough for a non-technical user to understand, though additional analogies would be nice to have.
Issue 2: No API
As mentioned above, I have to interface with the database directly. That's definitely less than optimal. I did mention to the third-party developers that it would be much preferable to have an API, but that has not happened.
Issue 3: No concurrency control
This is probably the more pressing issue. In this software, it's somewhat easy to show this is an problem. Essentially, the following happens:

User 1 opens a record.
User 2 opens the same record.
User 1 enters a change.
User 2 enters a change.
User 1 saves.
User 2 saves.

In this scenario, User 1 has lost their changes because the changes done by user 2 are saved over user 1 changes. User 1 has no idea they lost their changes. User 2 has no idea User 1 entered any changes.
This particular software is a web application and I tested by having two tabs open to the same record. Tab 1 being "User 1", and tab 2 being "User 2". Even with the lack of concurrency controls, I expected if tab 1 was refreshed, it would show me what's in the database (i.e. User 2 data). However, it still showed what User 1 had entered. Even with Ctrl+F5. So, apparently even if users are trying to verify their changes were saved, they aren't able to.
One again, from what I've been reading, I feel like the need concurrency control is up for debate. The argument against it seems to not so much be an argument against as an argument to ask the question "What are the chances this will happen?". In the context of this third-party software, I think the chances are low, but it still makes me nervous. We're dealing with money in this system, so I think there should be an extra level of concern here. My feeling is: Why risk it?
I have had discussions about this with our users and with this third-party going back about 5 years with no changes being made. The only real positive sign was their developer did ask me how we solved this in our software. Unfortunately that didn't seem to lead anywhere. Honestly, communication isn't great between the stakeholders here, so I don't know if it's an issue of not understanding the problem, not caring about the problem, or if it's thinking the risk is too low to worry about.
Assuming it's not just an issue of me being left out of the loop, I'd like to offer some examples of why we need to discuss this. I thought about using an analogy of multiple people trying to use the a single bathroom that doesn't have a lock on the door, but perhaps someone can give me a better analogy?
Final thoughts
I apologize for my first attempt at asking this question being too opinionated. I will admit I have strong opinions on what I consider the right way to handle these issues are. That's based on what I've been taught in school as well as 20 years of real world experience writing software as well as having to interface with software and libraries of varying quality.
I appreciate different viewpoints on these issues, though it does make it a little harder for the final concern I have. The question that keeps bouncing around in my head is whether these things are a sign that there may be other serious problems that are unknown. Not just to myself, but perhaps all the stakeholders. I suppose the only way to really know is to test, which I plan to do.

I’m voting to close this question because it is about a workplace issue, not an engineering one.

Obviously there's a workplace aspect to this question, but there are clearly also software design issues raised, and the workplace issue concerns communicating about software design. Closure is a bit harsh with this I think.

@Steve: well, the OP also asked specificially about 3rd party resources which might help them to solve this. This is off-topic for its own reasons, but the best thing I could provide here is pointing them to "The Workplace", which may actually already have the answers they are looking for.

@Steve: still, the question might be saved by a heavy rewrite, by removing the rants, removing the request for 3rd party resources and putting the technical part about concurrency issues into focus, the part which you answered (but which is not what the title asks).

I understand your frustration, but I don't really understand what you are asking? You seem to want ammunition to convince some "users" to use different software, but it is not clear what your options are for influencing these users or what alternatives there are for these users.

My hint for your rewrite: I think there is currently no sign in this question you try to behave unbiased. You have your opinion and seek for acknowledgement. Try a more scientific approach: you have a hypotheses ("the mentioned things will cause serious trouble for your company"), and now ask our community to falsify it. Then you know which of your arguments will withstand an attack, and which ones you may be overstating.

I didn't put it on the the workplace because I was hoping for technical responses to the specifics I mentioned. I thought I'd be a lot more likely to get that on software engineering.

@Dan: you asked how to better communicate with non-technical users. Honestly, that's not solved by gathering more technical reponses, as you said. You have to make an honest attempt to "wear a user's hat" and look at the situation from their perspective. Even more important, you have to look at this from a business perspective. Technical reasons are not an end in itself, they can only be judged in contrast to users needs and business needs.

... let me add I will be happy to cast a reopen vote after the rants and the 3rd-party resource request parts are removed.

Rewrite is done. Hopefully it's better. If it's still not good enough, that's fine. I probably won't try another rewrite since I'm not sure I can do any better.

@Dan; though your rewrite clearly improves the question, there is this major flaw of the general attitude. You still assume that your points are serious flaws which needs to be changed and that you just need a better explanation for the users. Sorry, but as long as you insist on that point-of-view, you won't convince anyone., neither your users  nor our community. You first need to start questioing your own dogma, that will help you with both. Nethertheless, I think give it a try and cast the final missing reopen vote, that gives others a chance to answer.

So you want to convince some users to stop using some third-party software which you consider flawed. But you don't even mention why the users use the software in the first place? Presumably it solves some problem for them. User are able to accept imperfect software as long as it is helps their day in some way - indeed all software is imperfect. This is where you should start: Understand why the users use the software. Then you can begin evaluating if there are better alternatives for the users, but remember to focus on the priorities of the users.


As mentioned in the thread I linked to, there are database issues. I may have been a little incorrect on my terminology in the original thread, but basically there are no foreign keys. From the responses in the original thread, it seemed like a mixed bag on whether that's a bad thing. I was taught to always have foreign keys and I believe it is smart. In the age old example of writing software to manage bank accounts, having a foreign key from Account to Customer I think is important. Imagine the ability for a bug or a poorly written ad-hoc query to delete Customer and be blissfully unaware that there are still Account rows.

This is a bit subjective really. I'd say it's common not to automatically enforce foreign keys in complicated applications, but instead to rely on the correctness of the programming which modifies the database.
The actual mechanics of the automatic enforcement and real-time checking of foreign keys tends to create everyday inconveniences in design, testing, and ongoing administration, as well as impairing performance at peak concurrency.
And if there is any kind of cascade behaviour, then it suffers from similar problems as triggers, which is that it causes the engine to react to ordinary commands in non-obvious ways. These reactions are non-local to the table(s) explicitly specified, and they are not always intended, or the performance implications can be unexpected.
The amount of additional hoop-jumping caused to the developer by encountering these constraints - such as having to reorder a series of statements which are already transactionally correct, so as to comply with the statement-level enforcement of FKs - can then beget additional errors and oversights on the basic task.

They have no concurrency control mechanism, nor do I get the opinion they even know what I'm talking about. It is perfectly possible for two users to open the same record, enter changes, and then whatever was on the screen of the second person to hit save is what gets saved. First person loses their changes. No notification to either user. No idea anything is wrong. Furthermore, when I tested this, I attempted to refresh the first user browser tab with both refresh and Ctrl+F5 expecting the screen to refresh and show the current database state (i.e. second users changes). But, it was still the first users changes. Literally, the only way user one could tell their changes weren't there would be to open a new tab in their browser and go to that record. The fact that they even had the bug originally 5 years ago surprises me.

It's certainly a flaw in that it does not check that the version of the record viewed and then edited by the user, was still the latest version available when the edit was submitted. I think this is widely regarded as a good practice and is not difficult to engineer.
It is a further flaw that for the other user, re-entering the screen does not reveal the loss/supersession of their edit. This is a bad practice, as users typically expect that entering a screen fetches the current data from source.
However, whether this is a big problem for your employer in practice depends on whether such concurrent edits are very common, and to what extent each user is influenced to make their edit by what they see on the screen.
Concurrency controls won't stop one user making an edit, then another user making an edit in a way that their access to the screens are non-overlapping, but their underlying activities are overlapping and perhaps unintentionally intermingling. This relies on overall business process analysis to identify and careful process engineering avoid.
There can also often be business processes that involve a staff member reviewing and using multiple screens where it's very difficult to maintain a guarantee of consistency across all the screens used in the procedure. When the problem is serious, a specific sequence of screens often have to be designed with special logic to deal with the risk, but when risks are small it may just be accepted.
Conclusion
I think there's the potential you may be fussing about legitimate problems, but problems to which you don't really have good solutions.
The foreign key thing is very much a mixed bag of issues, and not automatically enforcing the keys (and instead relying on code) is widely accepted as a legitimate design judgement.
Concurrency issues are the most common form of issue with multi-user applications, but the risks you describe are of the kind that are commonly accepted when the risks are small, and the flaws you've identified in the software may not contribute significantly to risks sustained under real-world usage of the application (nor would solving these specific flaws eliminate the whole risk, so your employer is likely still to end up sat bearing some risk).
Finally, if the only solution you propose involves huge costs (without demonstrable savings), or if it assumes the ability of development staff to react to your diagnosis and improve the software design (when they may already be operating at their limit and are unable to do better), then your employer won't be interested.


Issue 1: Database with no foreign keys

These days, I grant you, this is unusual.
However, for older applications, where the vendor tried to keep the database "vanilla" just in case they needed to port to, or to support, another DBMS, I can see why they'd do this.

.. it's something enforceable in code ...

This is third party software and they probably consider their database to be .. well .. theirs.  Their application knows how to handle the relationships and it's been coded to do so.  They don't feel they need for the database to "duplicate" the effort.

I feel like ad-hoc queries should be accounted for.

Foreign Keys make no difference to queries (except to inform "clever" query tools how the tables should be joined and, frankly, anyone needing such a tool should not be let anywhere near the Production database to being with).
Foreign Keys can make a lot of difference to updates, but nobody should be issuing those directly in the Production database anyway.

No API ... I have to interface with the database directly ...

Not ideal, but ought to be do-able, except ...

No concurrency control

This is an absolute show-stopper.
Business Change Concurrency Control is an absolute must, especially in the "disconnected" world of the Web Application.
Losing data changes should be a hanging offence.
For the application to not cater for this is grounds to throw the rotten thing out as simply Unfit for Purpose.  It shows a complete lack of understanding of a multi-user environment.
Now; how to express this to Management (non-technical and the ones that can influence this)?
Hit them where it hurts - Money and/or the Law.
No foreign keys but the application hangs together?
This isn't a fight you're going to win.
The response will be "The application can do it, why can't you?"
Accessing the database directly?
Again, if that's how the vendor tells you to do it (and they are telling you to do this, aren't they?) then that's how you have to do it.  It's their application, their database, their rules.
No Change Concurrency control?
Demonstrate the application's ability to lose data changes and do it with someone's Personal Data.  There are legal requirements for this data to be accurate and timely - if the application just loses changes, they should be very worried.
And then prepare yourself for the worst.
Management may still turn round and tell you to Just ... Do It anyway.

So, my worry with ad-hoc queries is mostly deletes. If there's a reason somebody has to write some queries to "fix" data that was mangled by a bug, it's very easy to delete records and have other records pointing to nothing. The FK keeps this from happening because you can't delete a record if it's referenced from a record in another table. It should be noted they have a much older application this app is replacing. It runs on an AS400. And it's apparently not uncommon to have "ghost records", which I suspect could be caused by something like no FKs. Though I don't know if AS400 supports FKs.

You wouldn't expect a window cleaner to perform open-heart surgery.
In the same way, you shouldn't allow anyone /anywhere near/ a Production database with "change" access who doesn't know exactly what they're doing!

You're having technical issues and want to sell those to non-technical (thus business) people.
You're going to have to find a business reason for them approving the changes you seek to make, not technical reasons. So for for example security issues, you'd have to point out (and provide examples and evidence of) those issues on the business. Showing how there are possible legal and financial consequences of those technical problems (without going into details about the technology itself) is what you need to do. And the same for anything else where the communication is targeted at non-technical people.
We're all non-technical to a degree, depending on topic/subject.
For example I have little interest in the technology driving my car, I just want the bloody thing to work. So don't go around telling me that changing to a new brand of engine oil will make my cylinder heads move better. Tell me that using that new oil will increase the life of my engine and thus my car, and reduce the cost of maintenance. And you'd better come up with figures to prove that claim, especially if the cost difference between the new oil and the current brand is significant!
